# ExtJS: Duplicate class name 'Ext.form.trigger.Spinner' specified, must be a non-empty string

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem sometimes appears on the console

```
[W] [Ext.define] Duplicate class name 'Ext.form.trigger.Spinner' specified, must be a non-empty string
```

Click + F5 Ctrl softkey disappears again just shake F5 appears and stops be updated grid.
How to keep track of these moments?

Thx.

P.S. Text was translated by Google translator

Comment: I have the same problem how you fix it?

Comment: I think it means you are loading  `'Ext.form.trigger.Spinner'` Class more than one On > `Ext.Loader`; when you extend 'Ext.form.trigger.Spinner' as new class, extjs check 'Ext.form.trigger.Spinner' and if does't exist get that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are defining a new class with the same name as a built-in Ext class. Change the name of your class to something other than `'Ext.form.trigger.Spinner'`, something that isn't a class name yet.

Comment: That's the thing that I do not have classes with the same name, otherwise the error would have been constantly